# Unable to delete a row in postgres db

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I am unable to delete a row in postgres db. This is what it shows

```
candlepin=# delete from cp_upstream_consumer where uuid = 'd88b0079-a271-4ee7-a7fe-ee3a1a7d5';

Cancel request sent
ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (0,5) in relation "cp_owner"
SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."cp_owner" x WHERE $1::pg_catalog.text OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "upstream_id"::pg_catalog.text FOR KEY SHARE OF x"
```

This has been hung for several minutes. And after I force quit, It says it has a relation with `cp_owner` column. But when if we try to delete `cp_column`, the db may crash. So is there any other way to delete the entry in `cp_upstream_consumer` table? Since I am new to postgres, I am unable to find out the possible alternatives.

This is what I have in cp_owner table

```
candlepin=# select * from cp_owner;
                id                |            created            |            updated            | contentprefix | defaultservicelevel | displayname | acco
unt | parent_owner |           upstream_id            | loglevel | autobind_disabled | content_access_mode | content_access_mode_list |        last_refreshe
d         | autobind_hypervisor_disabled
----------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+---------------------+-------------+-----
----+--------------+----------------------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+---------------------
----------+------------------------------
 021308a2752d917a01752d91b05d0001 | 2020-10-16 00:12:03.997+05:30 | 2021-04-16 16:08:32.789+05:30 | /COT/$env     |                     | COT         | COT
    |              | 021308a278d03bc50178da42c1a402bd |          | f                 | entitlement         | entitlement              | 2021-04-16 16:08:32.
781+05:30 | f
(1 row)
```

**EDIT**
After removing couple of postgres process I tried to re-run, and this is the new error when I try to run delete command

```
candlepin=# delete from cp_upstream_consumer where uuid = 'd88b0079-a271-4ee7-a7fe-ee3a1a7d5';
ERROR:  update or delete on table "cp_upstream_consumer" violates foreign key constraint "fk_upstream_consumer_id" on table "cp_owner"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(021308a278d03bc50178da42c1a402bd) is still referenced from table "cp_owner".
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`cp_upstream_consumer` has a foreign key to `cp_owner`, and there is a long running transaction that holds a lock on the referenced row.

Kill the database session that holds the lock, and you can delete the row.

Comment: Tried deleteing process, this is the error I am getting now: ERROR:  update or delete on table "cp_upstream_consumer" violates foreign key constraint "fk_upstream_consumer_id" on table "cp_owner"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(021308a278d03bc50178da42c1a402bd) is still referenced from table "cp_owner".

Comment: Please the the new EDIT part. @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Looks like you have a foreign key in the other direction as well. Delete all rows in `cp_owner` that depend on the row you want to delete. Read the tutorial in the PostgreSQL documentation on foreign keys.

Comment: Deleting the row in cp_owner leads to lose some of the important data. Anyother way other than deleting?

Comment: You cannot delete a row that is still referenced by a foreign key.